# Javascript prototype and issues accessing class

Tags: javascript, oop, class, object, prototype-programming

```
Family = function(name) {
  this._Name = name;
}

Family.prototype = {
  getName: function() {
    return this._Name;
  },
  People: function(num) {
    this._Number = num;
  }
}

Family.People.prototype = {
  clearNumber: function() {
    this._Number = 0;
  }
}
```

People is a nested class. Its parent class is Family.

I get the error that `Family.People` is undefined. Could someone correct the code above?

Comment: You may want to put var in front of Family and People, but, why not create a prototype for People, why do it for Family.People?

Comment: @James Black, that would give a syntax error in the second case... you can't have a var inside an object literal

Comment: The missing comma is at the end of line 3. Also, you definitely do not want to call `Family = new function(...) {...}`. `new` is used for object construction; in this case you just want `Family = function(...) {...}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Working code

```
// function doesn't need "new" operator
var Family = function(name) { this._Name = name; };

Family.prototype = {
    getName: function() { return this._Name; }, // missing comma
    People: function(num) {
        this._Number = num;
    }
};

// work with prototypes
Family.prototype.People.prototype = {
    clearNumber: function() { this._Number = 0; }
};
```

This will work. But you have to be aware, that when you call:

```
var f = new Family("Doe");
```

`f.People` is just an object constructor, and not an instance of some other object. You will have to instantiate it as well like:

```
f.members = new f.People(3);
```

Sou you have a constructor within your instance which is rather confusing.

### A better approach

So it would probably be better if you'd write your prototypes this way:

```
var Family = function(name) {
    this._Name = name;
    this.getName = function() { return this._Name; };
};

Family.People = function(num) {
    this._Number = num;
    this.clearNumber = function() { this._Number = 0; };
};
```

This actually makes a class within a class (and not within instances). So upper lines would be called this way:

```
var f = new Family("Doe");
f.members = new Family.People(3);
```

Drill down of `f` instance would look like:

```
f
  _Name
  getName()
  members
    _Number
    clearNumber()
```

### Private variables

```
var Family = function(name) {
    var _name = name;
    this.getName = function() { return _name; };
};

Family.People = function(num) {
    var _num = num;
    this.getNumber = function() { return _num; }
    this.clearNumber = function() { _num = 0; };
};
```

This way we make variables private and only accessible within so they can't be manipulated outside. You must always use functions to manipulate them. This makes it more robust especially when there are certain business rules related to variable values.

```
var f = new Family("Doe");
f._name; // this is undefined because "_name" is private closure variable
```

Drill down of `f` instance would now look more like a class object instance:

```
f
  getName()
  members
    getNumber()
    clearNumber()
```

Comment: @Robert Awesome ;] thanks for the smashing code example. +1 for readability

Comment: With @Robert's refactoring, you can also elect to close over `name` and `num` if desired, to preserve encapsulation.  Just refer to them directly and remove the assignment lines.

Comment: @Paul: Exactly! I updated my answer to include that information as well. Encapsulation makes them look as actual classes now...

Comment: @Robert: Cool, thanks for the hat tip. Technically, you don't even need to redeclare/assign the arguments in local scope, although that may be a point of style. I suppose it clearly shows we want to retain the argument.

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Check my edited answer that explains some more how to improve things even further.

Comment: @Paul: Huh I suspect I didn't write what you were talking about? I've added private variables so they're not accessible outside of local functions which makes it more robust. But I'm not sure that this is what you meant. Can you provide a short line of what you were talking about?

Comment: @Robert So you encourage non Prototype based scripting is it?

Comment: @Deeptechtons: No. Where did you get such impression? I'm just cleaning things up and making them more clear. Putting class constructor out of instance definitely is in the right direction. Have you ever been instantiating a subclass that was accessible only when parent class was instantiated? That's not even possible in C#. Anyway. I encourage prototyping. But if you think that not using keyword `prototype` makes things not prototyped you're wrong. It's just that I've encapsulated more inside a constructor without adding parts later as you originally did. My objects are still prototyped.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that you are assigning to `Family.prototype.People` then trying to access `Family.People`.

`Family` is not an *instance* of `Family` thus it does not have the properties of that class - `Family` is an instance of `Function` thus you are trying to access `Function.prototype.People` in that 3rd statement. (this is a bit of a simplification)

i.e. what you want to be doing is

```
Family.prototype.People.prototype = {
  clearNumber:function(){this._Number = 0;}
}
```

You are also missing a comma before people, but I assume this is a typo...

Comment: Could you correct that code. I understood most of that explanation but couldn't derive at a solution. All i will be doing is `var x = new Family('myName').Family.People.ClearNumber();` How do i do it properly.

Comment: see my edit (and why have you got that second Family there? you havn't set `Family.prototype.Family` so that would be undefined... what you want to call is `var x = new Family('myName').People.ClearNumber();`

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the People constructor as a key in the Family object:

```
Family.People = function(num) {
  this._Number = num;
}
```

The Family prototype will be in the prototype chain for new objects of type Family; not a part of Family itself.